# Button Click event is not fired in gridview button is added at RowDataBound event

Tags: asp.net, gridview

my .aspx design source code is

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdPaymentStatus" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    CssClass="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered table-advance table-hover" 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="ProjectStatusHeader" 
    OnRowDataBound="grdPaymentStatus_RowDataBound" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="instCount" HeaderText="Installments" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#dddddd" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="instPayment" HeaderText="Amount" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#dddddd" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="instWord" HeaderText="Words" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#dddddd" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="instPaymentMode" HeaderText="Payment Mode" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#dddddd" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="instPaymentdat" HeaderText="Payment Done On" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#dddddd" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="instIspaid" HeaderText="Payment Status" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#dddddd" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

.aspx.cs code is

```
protected void grdPaymentStatus_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text != "Paid")                    
        {
            Button sendRequestButton = new Button();
            sendRequestButton.ID = "PaymentRequest" + Row.Cells[0].Text;
            sendRequestButton.Text = "Send Request";
            sendRequestButton.CssClass = "btn blue";
            sendRequestButton.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
            sendRequestButton.CausesValidation = false;

            sendRequestButton.Click += new EventHandler(sendRequestButton_OnClick);

            e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(sendRequestButton);
        }
    }
}

protected void sendRequestButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AckNo))
        BindDetailsPayment(AckNo);
}
```

Data is binding at page load in (! isPostback) method and whenever i am trying to click on button added in gridview the button click event **(sendRequestButton_OnClick)** is not  firing
please help me out

thanks in advance.....

Comment: Kindly add the markup for **sendRequestButton**. Also, mention from where you are getting the value for **AckNo**.

Comment: Then **AckNo** is either `null` or `empty` so are been thrown out of **if** block

Comment: @ Suprabhat what i am trying to say is whenever i am click on button the sendRequestButton_OnClick event is not fired means that debug pointer is not coming at this sendRequestButton_OnClick event –

Comment: In previous comment you have mentioned it got fired!

Comment: sorry i want to say it is not fired if having any solution pls suggest me

Comment: @AnantDoshi You are using `BoundColumn` that is why you aren't able to get the event. Use a Template column instead.

Comment: @Amnesh Goel  their is one condition that it has to be 'if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text != "Paid") ' if true then it will add button if false then it will simply "paid"  in that cell

Comment: @AnantDoshi Solution is bit tricky for this... What you can do is.. 1. Use TemplateColumn 2. Place a label as well as LinkButton under that. 3 Using ItemDataBound event, you may select which one to show on your page (either label or button) 4. Link a JavaScript to user button and submit the form when user press the button. And then finally on service side handle the even.. If you're unable to do this.. I'll give u whole solution..

Comment: @Amnesh Goel thanks...  i think it will be great if you post answer

Comment: @AnantDoshi Did u solve it or still into problem.. then I'll start putting an asnwer

Comment: i have no idea how can i do the ** 4th point Link a JavaScript to user button and submit the form when user press the button. And then finally on service side handle the even.** so post answer

Comment: @AnantDoshi Rest do you understand?

Comment: `<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Payment Status">      
 <ItemTemplate>
  <a href="javascript:ExecutePaymentStatus();"
   title="Payment Status"> <img src="../images/SomeImage.gif" border="0"></a>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>`

Comment: @AnantDoshi add following to your JavaScript .. `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ExecutePaymentStatus() 
{
        document.YourFormName.hiddenAction.value="Launch";  
  document.YourFormName.submit();
}
</script>`

Comment: @AnantDoshi let me know if you don't understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90526/discussion-between-amnesh-goel-and-anant-doshi).

Answer (score 0):

Even though you bound it on row bound, you need to handle the event in RowCommand.

[See the following link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx).